# Error in Fedora Linux -- clock skew detected

Tags: fedora

How to solve the "Clock Skew detected. Your build may be incomplete" error in [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) Linux?

I am getting this error while using the `make` command in the terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compling C++ on remote Linux machine - "clock skew detected" warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824500/compling-c-on-remote-linux-machine-clock-skew-detected-warning)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely, cleaning up your codebase and then issuing 
`find . -exec touch {} \;`
does the trick.

as the link said:

```
Sometimes the last modified time on the files is wrong:
because it is greater than the time of day clock.  `make'
then issues the above message.
You usually see these sort of problems in programming
enviroments that use NFS to share files but don't sync
clocks using NTP.
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

## touch filename

will do all OK.

For more info:
http://embeddedbuzz.blogspot.in/2012/03/make-warning-clock-skew-detected-your.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen *[Clock skew detected. Your build may be incompleted.](http://www.linuxsa.org.au/pipermail/linuxsa/1999-August/008869.html)*?