# How to supress or correct this? make: warning: Clock skew detected. Your build may be incomplete

Tags: c, linux, build, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compling C++ on remote Linux machine - “clock skew detected” warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824500/compling-c-on-remote-linux-machine-clock-skew-detected-warning)

I tried everything about this:
I am using a cross compiler to build on x86 and run (execute) on a different platform. I am getting this warning.

I tried everything including:
[Error in Fedora Linux -- clock skew detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196747/error-in-fedora-linux-clock-skew-detected)
and also changing the timestamps of all executables (inside the target platform)

I need two things: 
     1) any soutions to this?
     2) How to supress this warning

Thanks in advance

FYI: I am using RPM build process to build my executables