# Can the make `-j` option cause a “clock skew detected” warning?

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

A few months ago, I noticed a `clock skew detected` warning when compiling something with make. I removed the `-j` option, and no longer got that warning. [I noted this in a question about the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35301514/3474956). The project has a complex dependency tree, and it seems possible that some parallel processors started building things before other processors finished. Apparently the SO community that saw my answer does not agree with it, and klimkin noted that I may have wrongly attributed this to the `-j` option. Can the `make` `-j` option cause the `clock skew detected` warning? Why?

Comment: Plain `make` will sometimes detect it. The number of jobs via the `-j` option does not affect it. I see it a lot when `scp'ing` files to IoT gadgets for testing. It happens most often when I use the `scp -p` option to preserve file times.

Comment: Do you run `make` on a computer but have your files served by a NFS server on another computer?

Comment: This was on a supercomputer....

Comment: This does not answer the question: are you working with an NFS server (which current time could be different from that of your supercomputer)?

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: My question isn't about that. My question is about whether it's possible for the `-j` option to cause the skew warning. Is it only possible on an NFS server?